# How can I specify s3 bucket as data source in Lake formation blueprint

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am trying to setup a data lake via `Lake Formation` blueprint. The source of my data are from `s3 bucket` and `kinesis stream`. When I select blueprint I can't find the option to choose `s3 bucket` as its source. Below is a screenshot of blueprint. How can I choose `s3` and `kinesis` as the data source?

[image]

Comment: Have you found out?